# Install ExePackage (or MsiPackage) depending on selected features in main MSI

Tags: wix, burn, windows-installer

Here is an issue.

Need to create WiX installer which will install the main MSI and additional ExePackage or MsiPackage depending on selected feature in the main MSI.

> MainMSI (feature A, feature B) -> Exe1 (only if feature A) -> Msi1
>   (only if feature B)

I know that WiX burn (or standard BA) processes InstallCondition before the chain starts being applied.
 
But is there any other way create such installer?

The variant with custom BA is inappropriate for this particular case.
Actually, I want similar logic as InstallShield has, when you may assign a redistributable on a specific feature.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible with Wix, but the [suite support from Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html) is exactly what you are looking for. Of course, what you see in that tutorial requires a paid edition, the Enterprise one.

Answer (score 0):

Installshield implement a special custom action call ISInstallPrerequisit that run after the `ReadyToInstall` (and thus after the Features selections) but before the `ExecuteAction` in the UI Sequence.

you could implement custom actions that launch your exe in the UI Sequence (Just before `ExecuteAction`) and use `&Feature` to decide to launch it or not.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, it's possible, but I don't want to modify a lot and include these prereqs into main MSI.